# Sync fails due to org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, spring

I am getting customer issues by throwing the following error.They are using mysql db

Synchronization is failed at Tue Dec 11 10:24:27 UTC 2018. Error is:
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException

I want to know

What might be the possibility for getting this issue and  what are the other informations required inorder to resolve this issue?

in which way we can debug and fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us a reproducible code-example which triggers the error

Answer (score 0):

DataIntegrityViolationException - Exception thrown when an attempt to insert or update data results in violation of an integrity constraint.

In most cases sync is inserting a null value into a column which has not null constraint. Other possibility: foreign key points to non existing id  (can be if order of syncing tables is wrong).

Ask for stacktrace log. Knowing which constraint name was throwing this exception will help you pinpoint the problem.